# Notice Message: Undefined variable: results AND Severity: Warning Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi I have been working on this code and for almost a day i just can't remove the error i have checked the internet but for somehow i wasn't able to find the solution i was looking for kindly help me with this thankyou very much
Here is the code

Controller

```
public function show() {

$data['results']= $this->User_model->get_users();

    $this->load->view('delete_view', $data);
```

Model

```
 public function get_users($id){
 $this->db->where('id', $id);
  $query = $this->db->get('users');
        return $query->result();
```

View

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php

foreach ($results as $show){
    echo $show->username;
    }

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you check if data is coming every time in the $results variable or not.

Comment: Refer this example . http://www.technicalkeeda.com/codeigniter-tutorials/display-records-from-database-using-php-codeigniter

Comment: data is not coming @PratikSoni

Comment: @Santosh ok sir let me look at it

Comment: @Santosh sir i have checked it and apply those changes but still the error remains

Comment: try to print ur $data in controller and check result key is avaible or not.

Comment: @dawoodbasharat: refer to your (3rd) comment on this question, that data is not coming, you can write empty check over that.

Comment: Also you are not sending any ```$id``` from controller, still you are accepting it in model.

Comment: @kishor10d can you reffer me the syntax where i'm not sending any $id?

Comment: ```$data['results']= $this->User_model->get_users();``` here you are not sending id. ```public function get_users($id){ }``` here you accepting ```$id```.

Comment: @kishor10d o thankyou sir!! my problem is solved now.. thanks alot for your help!!

Comment: which thing solve your problem? please mention that, so it will helpful for others too..

Comment: first of all my function was calling the wrong view and second i passed id so that's how it worked

Answer (score 1):

You passed a parameter in your model through where condition. unfortunately you didn't pass it through your controller. As your controller method, your model should be look like this.

```
public function get_users(){
   $this->db->select('*');
   $query = $this->db->get('users');
   return $query->result();
}
```